# Android - how to know if TalkBack is speaking to interrupt TTS?

Tags: android

I am working with TextToSpeech on Android to speak a sequence of texts. As it is a big string, I am using a new thread for this.

The problem is that when talkback speech accessibility is enabled, it stops reading my app to speak the notifications of the device, reads other buttons when the user touches the screen, etc.

I need to know when the talkback will speak, so I interrupt my thread and when the talkback finishes announcing whatever it is, my `tts` will be able to resume reading.

What is happening is that my `tts` reads line 1, line 2, line 3 (so talkback says something) and my `tts` did not read line 4, line 5 ... (...). It just resumes to speak after the talkback there to line 50, 60, since my repetition, that is in the thread, keeps running and the speaker is being occupied by the talkback.

Does anyone have any guidance / solution for this?

Comment: One simple solution would be to use a different speech engine for your app so Talkback doesn't interfere with it.  Also you could wait until each utterance is sucessfully completed (using utterancprogresslistener) before sending the next one.... OR... you could NOT use thread, send all the strings and use QUEUE.ADD (not flush) and that way after Talkback interrupts it, each string would restart.  Anyway... I'm having to guess because you're not including any code.

Comment: I'm doing the tts using QUEUE.ADD but it looks like Talkback flushes the queue, it's not restarting after talkback is finished

Answer (score 1):

You can override onStop method with UtteranceProgressListener. When user who use talkback does anything you can be notified through this method. BTW, onStop is not an abstract method so you should override yourself. I hope you have found it already :)

```
textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(
        new UtteranceProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(String utteranceId, boolean interrupted) {
        super.onStop(utteranceId, interrupted);
        yourCallback.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {

    }
});
```